# Are "from Table1 left join Table2" and "from Table2 right join Table1" interchangeable?

Tags: sql, join, left-join, right-join

For example, there are two tables:

```
create table Table1 (id int, Name varchar (10))

create table Table2 (id int, Name varchar (10))
```

Table1 data as follows:

```
    Id     Name     
    -------------
    1      A        
    2      B
```

Table2 data as follows:

```
    Id     Name     
    -------------
    1      A        
    2      B 
    3      C
```

If I execute both below mentioned SQL statements, both outputs will be the same:

```
select *
from Table1
  left join Table2 on Table1.id = Table2.id

select *
from Table2
  right join Table1 on Table1.id = Table2.id
```

Please explain the difference between left and right join in the above SQL statements.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
Select * from Table1 left join Table2 ...
```

and

```
Select * from Table2 right join Table1 ...
```

are indeed completely interchangeable. Try however `Table2 left join Table1` (or its identical pair, `Table1 right join Table2`) to see a difference. This query should give you more rows, since Table2 contains a row with an id which is not present in Table1.

Comment: So why do we need `RIGHT JOIN` if we can achieve any desired result with just `LEFT JOIN`? :P

Comment: `Select * from Table1 left join Table 2` will return ALL the records of table 1 plus coincident records of Table 2. The opposite `Select * from Table1 right join Table 2`would return ALL records from Table 2 and coincident records of Table 1. Hopes it helps.

Comment: if you use more then 2 tables , using right join can be meaningful and readable

Comment: @ProgramadorAdagal This doesn't explain why we have both, you can get same results with only one or the other: `SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2` and `SELECT * FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1`

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen you are changing a simple sentence of 7 words. When u have an 356 lines sentence with multiple  subsentences and need to change the logic of Left Right you ewill wonder changing it with only oneword...

Answer (score 43):

Table from which you are taking data is 'LEFT'.
Table you are joining is 'RIGHT'.
LEFT JOIN: Take all items from left table AND (only) matching items from right table.
RIGHT JOIN: Take all items from right table AND (only) matching items from left table.
So:

```
Select * from Table1 left join Table2 on Table1.id = Table2.id
```

gives:

```
Id     Name       
-------------  
1      A          
2      B
```

but:

```
Select * from Table1 right join Table2 on Table1.id = Table2.id
```

gives:

```
Id     Name       
-------------  
1      A          
2      B   
3      C
```

you were right joining table with less rows on table with more rows
AND
again, left joining table with less rows on table with more rows
Try:

```
 If Table1.Rows.Count > Table2.Rows.Count Then  
    ' Left Join  
 Else  
    ' Right Join  
 End If
```

Answer (score 12):

You seem to be asking, "If I can rewrite a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` syntax then why have a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` syntax at all?" I think the answer to this question is, because the designers of the language didn't want to place such a restriction on users (and I think they would have been criticized if they did), which would force users to change the order of tables in the `FROM` clause in some circumstances when merely changing the join type.

Comment: sometimes left and right outer joins are completely interchangeable, correct?

Comment: @Alex: indeed left and right outer joins are *always* interchangeable.

Answer (score 12):

```
select fields 
from tableA --left
left join tableB --right
on tableA.key = tableB.key
```

The table in the `from` in this example `tableA`, is on the left side of relation.

```
tableA <- tableB
[left]------[right]
```

So if you want to take all rows from the left table (`tableA`), even if there are no matches in the right table (`tableB`), you'll use the "left join".

And if you want to take all rows from the right table (`tableB`), even if there are no matches in the left table (`tableA`), you will use the `right join`.

Thus, the following query is equivalent to that used above.

```
select fields
from tableB 
right join tableA on tableB.key = tableA.key
```

Answer (score 10):

Your two statements are equivalent.

Most people only use `LEFT JOIN` since it seems more intuitive, and it's universal syntax - I don't think all RDBMS support `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: "I don't think all RDBMS support RIGHT JOIN" -- sure, not all RDBMSs support SQL. But if you are implying that some SQL products support `LEFT` but not `RIGHT` then please indicate which ones.

Comment: @onedaywhen For example, SQLite 3 doesn't implement `RIGHT` and `FULL OUTER JOIN `: http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html

Answer (score 0):

I feel we may require `AND` condition in `where` clause of last figure of `Outer Excluding JOIN` so that we get the desired result of `A Union B Minus A Interaction B`.
I feel query needs to be updated to

```
SELECT <select_list>
FROM Table_A A
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B B
ON A.Key = B.Key
WHERE A.Key IS NULL AND B.Key IS NULL
```

If we use `OR` , then we will get all the results of `A Union B`

Answer (score 0):

**select *
from Table1
left join Table2 on Table1.id = Table2.id**

In the first query **Left join** compares **left-sided** table **table1** to **right-sided** table **table2**.

In Which all the properties of **table1** will be shown, whereas in **table2** only those properties will be shown in which condition get true.

**select *
from Table2
right join Table1 on Table1.id = Table2.id**

In the first query **Right join** compares **right-sided** table **table1** to **left-sided** table **table2**.

In Which all the properties of **table1** will be shown, whereas in **table2** only those properties will be shown in which condition get true.

**Both queries will give the same result because the order of table declaration in query are different** like you are declaring **table1** and **table2** in **left and right** respectively in **first left join** query, and also declaring **table1** and **table2** in **right and left** respectively in **second right join** query.

This is the reason why you are getting the same result in both queries. So if you want different result then execute this two queries respectively,

**select *
from Table1
left join Table2 on Table1.id = Table2.id**

**select *
from Table1
right join Table2 on Table1.id = Table2.id**

Answer (score 0):

`Select * from Table1 t1 Left Join Table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id`
By definition: Left Join selects all columns mentioned with the "select" keyword from Table 1 and the columns from Table 2 which matches the criteria after the "on" keyword.

Similarly,By definition: Right Join selects all columns mentioned with the "select" keyword from Table 2 and the columns from Table 1 which matches the criteria after the "on" keyword.

Referring to your question, id's in both the tables are compared with all the columns needed to be thrown in the output. So, ids 1 and 2 are common in the both the tables and as a result in the result you will have four columns with *id* and *name* columns from *first* and *second* tables in order.

`*select *
from Table1
  left join Table2 on Table1.id = Table2.id`

The above expression,it takes all the records (rows) from table 1 and columns, with matching *id's* from table 1 and table 2, from table 2.

`select *
from Table2
  right join Table1 on Table1.id = Table2.id**`

Similarly from the above expression,it takes all the records (rows) from table 1 and columns, with matching *id's* from table 1 and table 2, from table 2. (remember, this is a right join so all the columns from table2 and not from table1 will be considered).