# MYSQL JOIN with AND error

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to pull first_name from Names table, but only if that users_id is in the Orders table and order_num = 1, but I keep getting an error.

```
SELECT first_name
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN orders
ON orders.order_id = customers.cust_id 
AND orders.order_num = 1
```

but my query is returning multiple values instead of just one, like it ignoring `orders.order_num=1` - does my query look right, or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps this chart can be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715677/difference-between-left-join-and-right-join-in-sql-server/4715847#4715847

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT first_name
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN orders
ON orders.order_id = customers.cust_id 
WHERE orders.order_num = 1
```

Comment: I've been wrestling around with joins for hours. I thought that the last `WHERE` clause would be for the first table? Anyway it works though!

Comment: Hey @Derp, please tag if this is solution to your problem. Motivates people to keep giving great answers!

Comment: Yeah, I guess there's a 10 minute timelimit - wouldn't let me xD  - TY WojtekT

Answer (score 0):

```
AND orders.order_num = 1
```

should be

```
WHERE orders.order_num = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT first_name
FROM customers
INNER JOIN orders
ON (orders.cust_id = customers.id)
WHERE orders.order_num = 1
GROUP BY customers.id
```

`INNER JOIN` will only include record where the `ON` condition matches

`WHERE` limits the results to only where order_num = 1

`GROUP BY` makes sure you only get 1 result for each customer