# is there need of RIGHT join, because we can achieve the same result using LEFT join by just altering the table name

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [right join versus left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807226/right-join-versus-left-join)

is there any need of RIGHT join, bacause we can achieve the same result using LEFT join by just altering the table name

i have two tables Persons and Orders

```
P_Id    LastName    FirstName   Address City
1   Hansen  Ola Timoteivn 10    Sandnes
2   Svendson    Tove    Borgvn 23   Sandnes
3   Pettersen   Kari    Storgt 20   Stavanger
```

and

```
O_Id    OrderNo P_Id
1   77895   3
2   44678   3
3   22456   1
4   24562   1
5   34764   15
```

and i have a query for left join as:

```
SELECT Persons.LastName, Persons.FirstName, Orders.OrderNo
FROM Persons
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Persons.P_Id=Orders.P_Id
ORDER BY Persons.LastName
```

and with right join:

```
SELECT Persons.LastName, Persons.FirstName, Orders.OrderNo
FROM Orders
RIGHT JOIN Persons
ON Orders.P_Id=Persons.P_Id
ORDER BY Persons.LastName
```

both gives the same result.

Comment: left and right joins are only easily interchangeable in the way you suggest if only two tables are involved in the query. [Otherwise the changes may need to be more extensive](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7313507/73226)

Answer (score 1):

Both versions exist for convenience.  Only one would be necessary, as you say.

However, sometimes a large query would have to be changed quite a bit if there were only one (RIGHT or LEFT) and you wanted to add a non-inner join to the query without changing it much.

With both as an option, it's usually easy to work a non-inner join into a pre-existing query without too much other reworking of the query.

At least that's the only time I find myself writing a RIGHT JOIN: when I already have a query and need to add in a non-inner join and making it a LEFT JOIN would cause me to rework the query more than I want to.

Comment: so is it only for user convenience. becuase some of databases like sqlite doesn't support RIGHT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: That's my understanding, yes.

Answer (score -1):

Check this for more understanding

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html