# Converting RIGHT JOIN to LEFT OUTER JOIN for fetching the same data

Tags: mysql, left-join, right-join

I have a table named Persons with the following data
[image]

The following query will fetch me the pid value in Persons table which is not equal to any of the PersonId values :

```
select B.pid
from Persons A
RIGHT JOIN Persons B ON (A.PersonID = B.pid)
where A.PersonID IS NULL
  AND B.pid IS NOT NULL
```

[image]

Is there a way to fetch the same data using LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between left join and right join in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715677/difference-between-left-join-and-right-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You should get the same result using `left join`, just by reversing the tables:

```
select B.pid
from Persons B LEFT JOIN
     Persons A
     ON A.PersonID = B.pid
where A.PersonID IS NULL AND B.pid IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: like... without using that B.pid IS NOT NULL in the original query.. will a left outer join help with that?