# PHP MS SQL Get Tables Velues even if some table as no value in the other one

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

I need some help I´m trying to get a list of all clients on my database, it is structured like this:
Table `Person` has the following fields

```
PersonId
FName
LName
Age
Gender
```

And I have another table with the name `PersonMoreDetail`
This one has the following fields:

```
PersonId
Adrdress
Nr
Location
Country
```

Where `PersonMoreDetail.PersonId` matches with the `Person.PersonId`.

And I have the following query:

```
SELECT     Person.*
FROM         Person INNER JOIN
                      PersonMoreDetail ON Person.PersonUId = PersonMoreDetail.PersonUId
```

And it shows only the Persons that have details in the table `PersonMoreDetail.PersonId`, so if you don't have details you will not appear, I don't know how to fix this, how to show the ones that do not have details on the list.

Comment: Try a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715677/difference-between-left-join-and-right-join-in-sql-server/4715847

Comment: @CD001 Thanks that's it!

Comment: @mim. Also thanks I'll read it , already started and it has good explanations about the joins  :D

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
    SELECT     Person.*
FROM         Person LEFT JOIN
                      PersonMoreDetail ON Person.PersonUId = PersonMoreDetail.PersonUId
```

Thanks to @CD001 and @mim. that helped me reach the answer!