# Left join vs Right join

Tags: sql, oracle

Do the following two queries produce the same result?

```
1.    SELECT * FROM Table a LEFT JOIN Table b ON a.id = b.id;

2.    SELECT * FROM Table b RIGHT JOIN Table a ON a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between left join and right join in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715677/difference-between-left-join-and-right-join-in-sql-server)

Comment: Yes they are the same. A right join is a left join written backwards to confuse everyone. I avoid them.

Comment: Just to expand on that, you'd normally read a `from` clause from left to right, e.g. `from customers` - OK this query is about customers - `join orders` - fine, I'm getting the orders for each customer - `join order_details` - got it, we also want the order details for each order. The optimiser may find a different join order, but when we write the query we can present the elements in a logical order to make it understandable. `RIGHT JOIN` violates that principle by forcing us to read a particular join in the opposite direction, which I personally find mildly infuriating.

Answer (score 0):

Yes both will provide same result with different sorting order

Comment: Thanks!Why the sorting order is different? Both are not sorted by "ORDER BY"

Comment: Agreed, there is no implication for sort order. Probably both will be internally transformed to the same query.

Answer (score 0):

No, the two are not the same because the columns are in different orders.  You are using `select *`, so the ordering of the columns is based on the order of the tables in `from` clause.

That said, with two tables, `left join` and `right join` are equivalent, with the tables switched and the same `join` conditions.  *This does not apply as more joins are added*.  So, these can be different:

```
select . . .
from a left join b left join c
```

versus:

```
select c right join b right join a
```

The reason is because of how the joins are grouped, which is always from left-to-right unless you have parentheses.

```
from (a left join b) left join c

select (c right join b) right join a
```

If you are interested in the more general situation (and perhaps examples of when they are not the same), then ask a *new* question.  That said, my advice is to always use `left join`s.  In my experience, `right join` is almost never needed.